# Why is my search form (supposed to hide on click of button) not hiding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I coded a simple search form that is supposed to hide/show on button click. But it is not working. Here isthe [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lakshkhamesra/8yze5f2r/).

HTML:-

```
<form class="search-form searchbar" role="search" id="hiddenSearchBox" action="" method="get">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="63">
    <input type="search" name="keywords" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="searchbar" data-target="#hiddenSearchBox">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> <span class="sr-only">Submit</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Can you spot the problem in the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lakshkhamesra/8yze5f2r/)?

Comment: Please add a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) which shows the actual problem in the question itself and not only post a link to an external resource.

Comment: Do you think on submit button, or something else?

Comment: After a quick look at the fiddle, you are using a button with `type="submit"`, if you don't `preventDefault` on the form submitting, it is submitted to the server. Since your form has an empty action, it reloads the page. It happens so fast you probably don't notice the page reload, but if you open up the dev tools in your browser and go to the network panel, when you press the button you will see a network request to confirm that is what is happening. Changing it to `type="button"` will prevent the form from submitting, but that doesn't seem to be the only problem.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need jquery for a simple show/hide.

anyway i have updated ur fiddle.

```js
document.getElementById('hideForm').onclick = function() {
document.getElementById('hiddenSearchBox').style.display = 'none';
}

// 
// hidden search bar to top right.
//

if (typeof jQuery === "undefined") { throw new Error("jQuery required"); }

+function ($) {
  'use strict';

  // SEARCHBAR CLASS DEFINITION
  // =========================

  var backdrop = '.searchbar-backdrop';
  var toggle   = '[data-toggle="searchbar"]';
  var Searchbar = function (element) {
    $(element).on('click.mr.searchbar', this.toggle);
  };

  Searchbar.VERSION = '1.0.0';

  Searchbar.prototype.toggle = function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.is('.disabled, :disabled')) return;

    var $parent  = getParent($this);
    var isActive = $parent.hasClass('open') || (typeof isXS == 'function' && isXS());

    if (!isActive) {
        
      clearMenus();
      if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement && !$parent.closest('.navbar-nav').length) {
        // if mobile we use a backdrop because click events don't delegate
        $('<div class="searchbar-backdrop"/>').insertAfter($(this)).on('click', clearMenus);
      }
      
      var relatedTarget = { relatedTarget: this };
      $parent.trigger(e = $.Event('show.mr.searchbar', relatedTarget));

      if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) return;
      e.preventDefault();

      $parent.find('input').trigger('focus');
      
      $parent
        .toggleClass('open')
        .trigger('shown.mr.searchbar', relatedTarget);

        return false;
    }
  };

  function clearMenus(e) {
    if (e && e.which === 3) return
    $(backdrop).remove();
    $(toggle).each(function () {
      var $parent = getParent($(this));
      var relatedTarget = { relatedTarget: this };
      if (!$parent.hasClass('open')) return;
      $parent.trigger(e = $.Event('hide.mr.searchbar', relatedTarget));
      if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) return;
      $parent.removeClass('open').trigger('hidden.mr.searchbar', relatedTarget);
    });
  }

  function getParent($this) {
    var selector = $this.attr('data-target');
    
    if (!selector) {
      return $this.parents('form');
    }

    var $parent = selector && $(selector);

    return $parent && $parent.length ? $parent : $this.parent();
  }


  // SEARCHBAR PLUGIN DEFINITION
  // ==========================

  function Plugin(option) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this = $(this);
      var data  = $this.data('mr.searchbar');

      if (!data) $this.data('mr.searchbar', (data = new Searchbar(this)));
      if (typeof option == 'string') data[option].call($this);
    });
  }

  var old = $.fn.searchbar;

  $.fn.searchbar             = Plugin;
  $.fn.searchbar.Constructor = Searchbar;


  // SEARCHBAR NO CONFLICT
  // ====================

  $.fn.searchbar.noConflict = function () {
    $.fn.searchbar = old;
    return this;
  };


  // APPLY TO STANDARD SEARCHBAR ELEMENTS
  // ===================================

  $(document)
    .on('click.mr.searchbar.data-api', clearMenus)
    .on('click.mr.searchbar.data-api', '.searchbar', function (e) { e.stopPropagation(); })
    //.on('focus.mr.searchbar.data-api', toggle, Searchbar.prototype.toggle) // this causes the focus event to trigger twice
    .on('click.mr.searchbar.data-api', toggle, Searchbar.prototype.toggle);


}(jQuery);
```

```html
<!-- hidden search bar to top right -->
        <form class="search-form searchbar" role="search" id="hiddenSearchBox" action="" method="get">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="63">
            <input type="search" name="keywords" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="searchbar" data-target="#hiddenSearchBox">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> <span class="sr-only">Submit</span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
   <button id="hideForm">
   Hide form
   </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply Add a button below the form in HTML & use jQuery on it as -

```js
$('#hide_form').on('click', function() {
 $('#hiddenSearchBox').toggle();    // toggle(false) will hide it permanently
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="search-form searchbar" role="search" id="hiddenSearchBox" action="" method="POST">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="63">
        <input type="search" name="keywords" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="searchbar" data-target="#hiddenSearchBox">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> <span class="sr-only">Submit</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<button id="hide_form">
    Hide Form
</button>
```